# KendoUI SPA - Is it possible to render a layout without it being wrapped in a div?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am creating an SPA with KendoUI-Web and my layout for the login view has a sticky header and footer.  To do this my divs that make up the view need to be direct children of the body.
I use the Following Code:

```
objLoginPage_Layout = new kendo.View('loginPage-layout');
objLoginPage_Layout.render($('body'));
```

However when I look in the Chrome Developer Tools I see that the layout is wrapped in a div.  This div breaks my CSS.

How can I tell KendoUI not to wrap my layout in a div?

Regards,

Scott

Answer (score 1):

Use KendoUI window.

I'm doing the same as you.

Here is their example http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/index.html

---

If you need, I can share my code, it is real simple, but try yourself first.

Comment: Sorry mate, but I'm not sure how this solves the problem.  The scope attribute of the style element is not supported atm:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_style_scoped
And I don't want my content in a popup window...  Have I mist what you are saying?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var theView = new kendo.View(template, { wrap: false });
```

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/view#methods-render